# How to generate an nginx log with unique id and add it in headers and send to php fpm using nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I want logs in both php and nginx with same id so that It makes analyzing the logs easier. I'm very new to nginx. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Do you mean you want to generate some random id for the request, add that id to the nginx access log line as a field and pass the same id to the PHP script via `fastcgi_pass` directive?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to ask for. Sorry for not being clear.